# Why do I get a "VBScript runtime error: Overflow" only when writing to a variable?

Tags: arrays, import, vbscript, tia-portal

I need some assistance from any of the VBScript wizards out there.

I'm currently working on Import/Export functions which are capable of moving data between an SD card local to an industrial PLC, and a USB local to an HMI (control panel). This is all being programmed in the Tia-Portal V15.1 programming environment.

When the export function is initiated, the PLC breaks down all 64135 bytes of data from its local SD card into a transfer buffer (*ie. multiple arrays of bytes (`array[array[bytes]]`)*) in a data block (DB). The transfer buffer is referenced by the HMI, and can be accessed without issue by the VBScripts called within. This is done by referencing the variable `USBSD_Interface_TransferBuffer.Datapack_#`. Using a FOR-loop, the VBScript counts through each of the elements, and can write them to a log file on the connected USB:

```
'#############################################################################################
'#                            HANDSHAKE TO WRITE DATA TO FILE                                #
'#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
Dim LOCAL_BUFFERSIZE : LOCAL_BUFFERSIZE = 1599          ' Array[0..1599] = 1600 entries
Const MAX_ARRAYSIZE = 64135                             ' Max number of elements in array
Const MAX_ARRAYCOUNTER = 40                             ' 40 * 1600 = 64000 values
Dim BUFFER_COUNTER : BUFFER_COUNTER = 0
Dim ARRAY_COUNTER : ARRAY_COUNTER = 0
'#############################################################################################

For ARRAY_COUNTER = 0 To MAX_ARRAYCOUNTER
    If ARRAY_COUNTER = MAX_ARRAYCOUNTER Then
        ' Catch case of final datapack only holding 135 elements
        LOCAL_BUFFERSIZE = 135  
    End If
    
    For BUFFER_COUNTER = 0 To LOCAL_BUFFERSIZE
        FILE.WriteLine SmartTags("USBSD_Interface_TransferBuffer.Datapack_" & ARRAY_COUNTER)(BUFFER_COUNTER)
    Next
Next
```

Although reading from the array and writing the data to an external file worked without issue, the same cannot be said for the *Import* function. Here, I attempted to do the exact same thing, yet in reverse. I first load the file and place each entry into a variable (`FILEDATA`), which is essentially an array of values. These values are then iterated through, and written to the corresponding position in the transfer buffer:

```
'#############################################################################################
'#                         HANDSHAKE TO WRITE DATA TO TEMP-DB                                #
'#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
Const MAX_ARRAYSIZE = 40
Const MAX_ELEMENTS = 64135
Dim LOCAL_BUFFERSIZE : LOCAL_BUFFERSIZE = 1599
Dim ARRAY_COUNTER : ARRAY_COUNTER = 0
Dim BUFFER_COUNTER : BUFFER_COUNTER = 0
Dim ELEMENT_COUNTER : ELEMENT_COUNTER = 0
'#############################################################################################

For ARRAY_COUNTER = 0 To MAX_ARRAYSIZE
    If ARRAY_COUNTER = MAX_ARRAYSIZE Then
        LOCAL_BUFFERSIZE = 135
    End If
    
    For BUFFER_COUNTER = 0 To LOCAL_BUFFERSIZE
        SmartTags("USBSD_Interface_TransferBuffer.Datapack_" & ARRAY_COUNTER)(BUFFER_COUNTER) = CByte(FILEDATA(ELEMENT_COUNTER))
        ELEMENT_COUNTER = ELEMENT_COUNTER + 1
    Next
    
    If ELEMENT_COUNTER >= MAX_ELEMENTS Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

I'm currently getting the following error when running my script:

> 0x800a0006 - Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Overflow: 'BUFFER_COUNTER'

This only occurs during the **Import** phase, when the counter reaches `BUFFER_COUNTER = 99` of the first datapack (ie. `ARRAY_COUNTER = 0`).

Out of sheer desperation, I tried brute-forcing the first 100 variables by hand to see if the FOR-loop was causing a problem via:

```
SmartTags("USBSD_Interface_TransferBuffer.Datapack_0")(0) = CByte(FILEDATA(0))
SmartTags("USBSD_Interface_TransferBuffer.Datapack_0")(1) = CByte(FILEDATA(1))
SmartTags("USBSD_Interface_TransferBuffer.Datapack_0")(2) = CByte(FILEDATA(2))
...
SmartTags("USBSD_Interface_TransferBuffer.Datapack_0")(99) = CByte(FILEDATA(99))
SmartTags("USBSD_Interface_TransferBuffer.Datapack_0")(100) = CByte(FILEDATA(100))
```

... which resulted in the same overflow error at position `99`. I know all of the transfer buffer arrays are instantiated, because I can read/write their values individually. For example, calling:

```
SmartTags("USBSD_Interface_TransferBuffer.Datapack_0")(99) = CByte(FILEDATA(99))
SmartTags("USBSD_Interface_TransferBuffer.Datapack_0")(100) = CByte(FILEDATA(100))
SmartTags("USBSD_Interface_TransferBuffer.Datapack_0")(101) = CByte(FILEDATA(101))
SmartTags("USBSD_Interface_TransferBuffer.Datapack_0")(102) = CByte(FILEDATA(102))
```

... results in no error. This error only seems to arise when I attempt to **write** to more than `98` elements in the array during the VBScript's execution.

I'm really at a loss with this one. If anyone has run into a similar issue before, any tips/tricks/workarounds would be very much appreciated!

Comment: You go through the loop 41 times.

Comment: Add `MAX_ARRAYSIZE - 1` to the `For` loop, so you don’t exceed the maximum array size of 40. As @user18521918 points out 0 to 40 is 41 iterations not 40 which is what you specify as the `MAX_ARRAYSIZE`.

Comment: @user692942 , @user18521918 Thank you for the notice, but the 41 iterations `[0...40]` is intentional!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking to other professionals on the matter, the reason for this error has been found. The "overflow" is **not** an overflow of the counter variable, but an overload condition of the processing time/power of the hardware when writing too many variables, in too short of a time (*irregardless what the Microsoft error said*).

The recommended solution was to create a pause or time-loop to force the HMI to stop and process the already-called variables, before attempting to write to new ones. The loop would be nestled in the main FOR-loop, and would look something like this:

```
If ELEMENT_COUNTER Mod 50 = 0 Then
  Dim WAIT_TIME : WAIT_TIME = Now + 1 / 24 / 3600 ' wait for one second
  Do
  Loop While Now <= WAIT_TIME
End If
```

This recommendation unfortunately came too late: I had already created a temporary solution of my own, which inadvertently circumvented the issue, without realizing exactly what the issue was. I created a secondary buffer of 50 bytes in the PLC which is filled by the HMI. Once filled, the HMI sends a signal to the PLC, and the PLC systematically fills the main buffer with the values in the secondary buffer, before sending a signal to the HMI to continue the process. This handshake continues until the main buffer is filled.

I believe I will make my temporary solution more 'permanent', regardless the fact it is a little slower than the recommended solution. If I'm not mistaken, it is a general rule of thumb in programming to avoid the use of pauses and wait-functions, unless the calling function itself is time-dependent. Even then, they should be treated with caution.